# Get all the data from a REST API including nested API links

Tags: json, pandas, api, dataframe

I am trying to retrieve JSON data from the rest API [SWAPI](https://swapi.dev/documentation) which has information about  `people`, `films`, `starships` and `planets` within the StarWars universe.

Here is my code:

```py
total_results = []

for page_num in range(1, 7):
    # Build the URL and download the results
    url = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=" + str(page_num)
    print("Downloading", url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    total_results = total_results + data['results']

print("We have", len(total_results), "total results")

SW_people_df = pd.json_normalize(total_results)
SW_people_df.head()
```

Here is how the dataframe looks like:

|  | name | height | mass | hair_color | skin_color | eye_color | birth_year | gender | species | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Luke Skywalker | 172 | 77 | blond | fair | blue | 19BBY | male | [] | http://swapi.dev/api/people/1/ |
| 1 | C-3PO | 167 | 75 | n/a | gold | yellow | 112BBY | n/a | ['http://swapi.dev/api/species/2/'] | http://swapi.dev/api/people/2/ |
| 2 | R2-D2 | 96 | 32 | n/a | white, blue | red | 33BBY | n/a | ['http://swapi.dev/api/species/2/'] | http://swapi.dev/api/people/3/ |
| 3 | Darth Vader | 202 | 136 | none | white | yellow | 41.9BBY | male | [] | http://swapi.dev/api/people/4/ |
| 4 | Leia Organa | 150 | 49 | brown | light | brown | 19BBY | female | [] | http://swapi.dev/api/people/5/ |

#### My question:

Is it possible to retrieve the data from the API including the nested links? i.e. getting the actual JSON information from the nested links in the column `SW_people_df['species']` instead of a list of links.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting requirement

- download all the people (same approach as you just more compressed code)
- check each of the columns to see if it contains a link ("http")
- create a dictionary of all the columns that contain a link with a dataframe that is concatenation of results of all links in that column
- now have all data,  so you can merge/join and analyse across each data categories

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# people - pages 1 to 7
dfp = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(requests.get(f"https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page={p}").json()["results"]) for p in range(1,7)])


# get all the related data from urls against ppl
linkeddf = {c:pd.concat([
    pd.json_normalize(requests.get(u).json()) for u in dfp[c].explode().dropna().unique()
]) for c in dfp.columns if dfp[c].explode().str.contains("http").any() and c!="url"}


# join ppl to homeworld
dfp.merge(linkeddf["homeworld"], left_on="homeworld", right_on="url", suffixes=("_person","_world"))

# what films has a skywalker been in?
(dfp.explode("films").merge(linkeddf["films"], left_on="films", right_on="url", suffixes=("_person","_film"))
 .loc[:,["name","title"]]
 .query("name.str.contains('Sky')")
)
```

### output

```
                 name                    title
0      Luke Skywalker               A New Hope
17     Luke Skywalker  The Empire Strikes Back
33     Luke Skywalker       Return of the Jedi
53     Luke Skywalker      Revenge of the Sith
61   Anakin Skywalker      Revenge of the Sith
79   Anakin Skywalker       The Phantom Menace
94     Shmi Skywalker       The Phantom Menace
115  Anakin Skywalker     Attack of the Clones
123    Shmi Skywalker     Attack of the Clones
```