# R Studio display list of films in tidyverse starwars data set

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am learning R and R studio.  I can print out the star wars tibble  and select variables.  However, I can figure out how to list all the elements in the list variable (films).  e.g. is in 5 films but how do I code that to print out all the names?  This answer might contain what I need but I am just starting and haven't yet learned explode and merge.

[Get all the data from a REST API including nested API links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016629/get-all-the-data-from-a-rest-api-including-nested-api-links)

```
library(tidyverse)
select(starwars, name, species, films)
```

Comment: Just fyi the link you included is in Python, not R

Comment: Hi Camille,  I am running this in R, in Rstudio.  from the book, R for Data Science.

Comment: Right, but the link you posted is an SO post about doing something similar in Python. Specifically `explode` is a pandas function, but I don't know that there's a similar operation with the same name in R

Comment: Thanks Camile, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::unnest`

```r
library(tidyverse)
select(starwars, name, species, films) %>% 
  unnest(films)
#> # A tibble: 173 × 3
#>    name           species films                  
#>    <chr>          <chr>   <chr>                  
#>  1 Luke Skywalker Human   The Empire Strikes Back
#>  2 Luke Skywalker Human   Revenge of the Sith    
#>  3 Luke Skywalker Human   Return of the Jedi     
#>  4 Luke Skywalker Human   A New Hope             
#>  5 Luke Skywalker Human   The Force Awakens      
#>  6 C-3PO          Droid   The Empire Strikes Back
#>  7 C-3PO          Droid   Attack of the Clones   
#>  8 C-3PO          Droid   The Phantom Menace     
#>  9 C-3PO          Droid   Revenge of the Sith    
#> 10 C-3PO          Droid   Return of the Jedi     
#> # … with 163 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you this is what I was looking for but had not yet learned.

Comment: glad to help! can you mark my post as the best answer, please?